# Can't rename sheets in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a simple script to take a bunch of sheets sheets from different work books and put them on one work book. I have to rename all the sheets so that they work with other scripts that I have. All of the sheets get renamed just fine except for the sheets I am getting from the eod loop. The first 2 sheets get renamed just fine but after that none of them in the loop do. The all of the workbooks that the eod sheets are coming from are in xlsx format and the rest are xls format. Every sheet that I put in that is in xls will close when the macro is done, but all the xlsx format files will not. I don't know if this is part of the problem or not. What would cause this to only rename certain sheets?

```
     Sub getSheets()
        num = 1
 ----->   ' loop for eod 
        Do Until copyover("Weekly", "EOD Week " & num) = False
            num = num + 1
        Loop

        temp = copyover("Voice_of_the_Customer", "VOC")
        temp = copyover("Daily_Cp%_v2", "COMP")
        temp = copyover("MPJ-Scorecard-QC-Summary", "QC")
        temp = copyover("MPJ-Scorecard-SCOI-Summary", "SCOI")
        temp = copyover("TechUpstreamTransmit", "UPSQ")
        temp = copyover("Daily_CCG_OTG", "MTF")
        temp = copyover("summary", "S7 QC")
        temp = copyover("MPJ-Scorecard-TCF-Summary", "TCF")

    End Sub

Function copyover(SheetAd As String, SheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim origWork As Workbook
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim copytoFile As Variant
    Dim copytoFile2 As Workbook
    Set origWork = ActiveWorkbook

    tem = MsgBox("Do you want to add " & SheetName, vbYesNoCancel)
    If (tem = vbYes) Then
        copyover = True
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        copytoFile = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (Title:=SheetAd, _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files *.x* (*.x*),")
        Workbooks.Open copytoFile
        Set copytoFile2 = ActiveWorkbook
        copytoFile2.Sheets(SheetAd).Move After:=origWork.Sheets("TechScore")
        'ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
        origWork.Activate
        origWork.Sheets(SheetAd).Name = SheetName
        'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(SheetAd).Name = "Mudface"
         Workbooks(copytoFile).Close False
    Else
    If (tem = vbNo) Then
          copyover = False
    End If
    End If

ErrHandler:

End Function
```

Comment: How do you create your destination file? Is it possible that it only has 65536 lines and that it therefore cannot accomodate the xlsx worksheets?

Comment: the worksheet copies fine but it just wont rename the third on in the loop and on. and there is only 120 lines on the sheet that I am importing.

Comment: stay away from `ActiveWorkbook` as much as possible. It's really a dangerous way to go. Change `Set origWork = ActiveWorkbook` to `Set origWork = Workbooks("whateveryourwbnameis.xlsx")` and `Set copytoFile2 = ActiveWorkbook` to `Set copytoFile2 = Workbooks(copytoFile)` Then, set your breakpoints... it will help you understand why the code doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: do you know how to step through your code?  try stepping through your code and see if your function is error'ing out

Comment: I steped through the code and relized that the error handler was hiding the errors. I got rid of the error handler and I found that the reason I was not able to name the last 3 sheet is because the name was already in use. I had hidden the other file before so i just deleted that and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult for me to follow.  It looks like you're living rather dangerously in how this is coded.  origWork is never initialized.  It might help you if you put 'option explicit' above all the code in your module/sheet code.  I think part of your work is basically getting lost in memory somewhere and never ending up where you think it did.  Try adding a breakpoint at some of the key lines and checking what workbooks are being referenced.  It's one very very nice thing about VBA because you can debug/edit variables while it's running.

Comment: Yeah, I was tempted to re-write the code for him, but I'm too busy at work today. +1 for typing what i as thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename only certain sheets with specific names, I have made a couple macros to do this quickly:

Macro 1

```
Sub Sheetlist()
Dim x As Integer

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "sheetlist"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sheet List"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New List"
For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
Next x
End Sub
```

This creates a sheet in your workbook called sheetlist will the list of all sheets in your current workbook. You can eliminate any sheet names you do not want to rename with the next macro, but make sure there are no blanks.

There is a column entitled "New List" (C) that you can place the list of names you want the sheets to be called. Make sure this sheet has the same number of names as column A.

Macro 2:

```
Sub batchrename()
'
' batchrename Macro
'
Dim OldSheetName As String
Dim NewSheetName As String
Dim SheetCount As Integer
Dim NewSheetList As String

NewSheetList = InputBox("How many names are there?") + 1
For SheetCount = 1 To Range("C2:C" & NewSheetList).Count
OldSheetName = Sheets("sheetlist").Cells(SheetCount + 1, 1)
NewSheetName = Sheets("sheetlist").Cells(SheetCount + 1, 3)

Sheets(OldSheetName).Select
ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheetName
Next SheetCount

End Sub
```

This will rename the sheets from A to the names in C. The prompt will ask you where the list of names are, input the full range of where the new list of names are (Ex: C2:C250), and hit enter.

Hope this helps,